# Nsnumber intvalue exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, ios8, exc-bad-access, nsnumber, nsinteger

Since I upgraded to iOS 8, I have the following lines of code :

```
NSNumber *balance = dict[@"user"][@"balance"];
[IWSession session].currentUser.balance = [balance integerValue];
```

which generate sometimes a exc_bad_access

1) This is totaly random

2) By setting a `NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"user"][@"balance"])`, I can tell that the value is never `nil` and the object type a `NSNumber`

3) `IWSession.session` is a singleton instance and the `currentUser.balance` is a `NSInteger` which is well synthetized.

Any idea of 
what can be wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you could be failing fetching `currentUser` or storing into `currentUser.balance`.  But if the NSNumnber `balance` is  bad it's probably because it went bad inside the dictionaries, due to some sort of ARC-relates snafu.  Use Zombies et al to diagnose.

Comment: (I assume that the bogus `[` at the very start of your code is a typo in the post and not actually in your code.)

Comment: Thanks. Yep typo Error, I just updated.

currentUser is ok if I log it (everytime).
The issue might be the storage of the value or as you said it, the NSNumber itself.

I will go deeper in the issue.

Comment: Find my issue thanks to your suggestion of using NSZombie. Add it as an answer and I will accept it ! Thanks
Romain

Comment: How were you able to fix this?